# Stuck at getting all the links exhausting view more button using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script to fetch the link of different containers from the two identical links. The script is doing fine as long as the first page is concerned. However, there is a button at the bottom `View More` which does not have any link associated with it so, I'm stuck at getting the rest using requests. To bring out the clarity, the following image represents the first container of the first link.

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://hipages.com.au{}'

links = (
    'https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/sa/adelaide',
    'https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/vic/melbourne'
)

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'  
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
        for item in soup.select("[class*='BusinessListingHeaderColumn'] a:has(> h3)[href]"):
            print(base.format(item.get("href")))
```

> How can I get the links from all the containers making use of `view more` button using requests?

This is the type of output I'm after:

```
https://hipages.com.au/connect/cinemaathome
https://hipages.com.au/connect/mrcommunications
https://hipages.com.au/connect/adelaidevideoscreens
```

Comment: what is this `a:has(> h3)[href]` supposed to do? which anchor tag are you looking for?

Comment: I'm sure you forgot to take a look at the description along with the image and the expected output where I've clearly mentioned what I'm after. Given that the selector is targeting the first anchor tag associated with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` might not be the best tool for this type of the job, because you have to keep adding more content to the page dynamically.

One workaround would be to use an API, as there's one. But I found several problems with this request for example:

```
https://hipages.com.au/api/directory/sites?suburb=adelaide&state=sa&category=145&page=2&perpage=10&code=c237ab1d599590b23f25c822a43c74528d7d55182331509852906e86cf0710b1c1d72087cbbbaa1f4ff8dcb50c9f234e
```

1. You'd have to somehow map the `category=145` value to its name.
2. I wasn't able to figure out where the `code` part is coming from.

Another workaround would be to, well, keep clicking on the `View more` button until there's no such button. Then, scrape the "final" version of the page for all the urls matching the `css` selector.

Repeat for the next url and so on...

How? Enters `selenium`.

PS. To get this running, apart from the `selenium` module, you need the Chrome driver. See [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for installation instructions.

The code:

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


base = 'https://hipages.com.au{}'
links = (
    'https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/sa/adelaide',
    'https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/vic/melbourne'
)

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

for link in links:
    print(f"Fetching connect links for {link}...")
    driver.get(link)

    while True:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.jRFKbg').click()
            time.sleep(2)  # wait for more content to load
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    follow_links = BeautifulSoup(
        driver.page_source,
        "html5lib",
    ).select("[class*='BusinessListingHeaderColumn'] a:has(> h3)[href]")

    for follow_link in follow_links:
        print(base.format(follow_link.get("href")))
```

This outputs (for Adeladie):

```
https://hipages.com.au/connect/cinemaathome
https://hipages.com.au/connect/mrcommunications
https://hipages.com.au/connect/adelaidevideoscreens
https://hipages.com.au/connect/justantennas
https://hipages.com.au/connect/celciustechnicalservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/ljhelectricalsolutions
https://hipages.com.au/connect/voltechservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/comtelecom
https://hipages.com.au/connect/homedigitalsystems
https://hipages.com.au/connect/samedaytvantennaservice
https://hipages.com.au/connect/pheds
https://hipages.com.au/connect/parksidedigitaltvservice
https://hipages.com.au/connect/antennatoday
https://hipages.com.au/connect/getfusedelectricalptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/switchedonwiring
https://hipages.com.au/connect/lightningelectricalsolutionssa
https://hipages.com.au/connect/evanselectricalandair
https://hipages.com.au/connect/lynchelec
https://hipages.com.au/connect/asapantennas
https://hipages.com.au/connect/spacetelecommunications
https://hipages.com.au/connect/outpulseelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/markgentle
https://hipages.com.au/connect/matchmastertvreceptionsystems
https://hipages.com.au/connect/empireelectricalsa
https://hipages.com.au/connect/sasecureservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/powerlux
https://hipages.com.au/connect/ecolightselectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/kdiselectricalandairconditioningservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/jptelecomptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/bhullarelectricalsandsolar
https://hipages.com.au/connect/tkhelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/njstechnologies
https://hipages.com.au/connect/apexelectricalsolarservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/handymanservice6
https://hipages.com.au/connect/pricelesselectricalptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/zaccelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/adelaidehometheatre
https://hipages.com.au/connect/wescombeelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/batterselectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/avanditconnections
https://hipages.com.au/connect/andersonelectric
https://hipages.com.au/connect/tappelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/smartgridelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/scothernselectricaldataservicesptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/nexuselectricalairconditioning
https://hipages.com.au/connect/apcelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/paultompkinselectricalcontracting
https://hipages.com.au/connect/aaronlampreelectricalservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/sparrowelectricalandconstructionservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/djairelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/localchoiceelectrical
https://hipages.com.au/connect/knicelectricalservicesptyltd
```

EDIT:

This is based on your own answer you've shared with me. Basically, you couldn't break out of the loop because the API kept serving you the last page over and over again even if it was the *same* page.

So, we need to know when we've seen the page or the follow link. Here's my attempt, which boils down to checking if any lead link from the API is in the list of all follow links. If so, we've seen this API page. Time to move on to the next URL.

```
import re
import requests

lead_link = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/"
links = (
    "https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/sa/adelaide",
    "https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/vic/melbourne",
)

all_follow_links = []
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    print(f"Getting links for {link}...")
    payload = {
        "suburb": link.split("/")[-1],
        "state": link.split("/")[-2],
        "category": re.search(r'category_id":(.*?),', r.text).group(1),
        "page": 1,
        "perpage": 10,
        "code": re.search(r'"code":"(.*?)",', r.text).group(1),
    }
    while True:
        response = requests.get(
            'https://hipages.com.au/api/directory/sites?',
            params=payload,
        ).json()
        leads = [f"{lead_link}{item['siteKey']}" for item in response]
        if any(lead in all_follow_links for lead in leads):
            break
        all_follow_links.extend(leads)
        payload["page"] += 1

print(all_follow_links)
```

Comment: Hi @baduker, thanks for your answer. I'm almost done solving it using requests which is fetching the result flawlessly except for the fact that I can't let the script break out of while loop.

Comment: Oh, let me know how you figured it out with requests once you get this done, as I'm really curious!

Comment: I suppose you wanna give the other answer a look. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Good job on finding out the `code` stuff!

Comment: This how I rectified [the script](https://pastebin.com/bRmK7p9z). Your suggested one works though.

Comment: I was thinking about using a set too, actually this might be a better choice for this type of scrape data.